# Make AngularJS routes named groups non-greedy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, greedy

Given the following route:

```js
$routeProvider.when('/users/:userId-:userEncodedName', {
    ...
})
```

When hitting the URL `/users/42-johndoe`, the `$routeParams` are initialized as expected:

```js
$routeParams.userId // is 42
$routeParams.userEncodedName // is johndoe
```

But when hitting the URL `/users/42-john-doe`, the `$routeParam` are initialized as follow:

```js
$routeParams.userId // is 42-john
$routeParams.userEncodedName // is doe
```

Is there any way to make the named groups non-greedy, i.e. to obtain the following `$routeParams`:

```js
$routeParams.userId // is 42
$routeParams.userEncodedName // is john-doe
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the path

from

```
$routeProvider.when('/users/:userId-:userEncodedName', {});
```

to

```
$routeProvider.when('/users/:userId*-:userEncodedName', {})
```

As stated in the [AngularJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider) regarding `$routeProviders`, `path` property:

> path can contain named groups starting with a colon and ending with a
>   star: e.g.:name*. All characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams
>   under the given name when the route matches.

Comment: This **[indeed works](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2aLbB/4)**, but from reading the docs I really expected it to do the exact opposite. Strange !

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough **[Ryeballar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067884/make-angularjs-routes-named-groups-non-greedy#answer-24068368)** does indeed work (as is demonstrated in this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2aLbB/)**). I say "oddly enough", because based on the docs (*"[...] characters are eagerly stored [...]"*), I would expect it to work exactly the opposite way.

---

So, out of curiosity, I did some digging into the source code (v1.2.16) and it turns out that by a strange coincidence it indeed works. (Actually, this looks more like an inconsistency in the way route-paths are parsed).

The `pathRegExp()` function is responsible for converting the route path template into a regular expression, which is later used to match against the actual route paths.
The code that converts the route path template string into a RegExp pattern is the following:

```
path = path
    .replace(/([().])/g, '\\$1')
    .replace(/(\/)?:(\w+)([\?\*])?/g, function(_, slash, key, option){
        var optional = option === '?' ? option : null;
        var star = option === '*' ? option : null;
        ...
        slash = slash || '';
        return ''
            + (optional ? '' : slash)
            + '(?:'
            + (optional ? slash : '')
            + (star && '(.+?)' || '([^/]+)')
            + (optional || '')
            + ')'
            + (optional || '');
    })
    .replace(/([\/$\*])/g, '\\$1');
```

---

Based on the code above, the two route path templates (with and without `*`) end up in the following (totally different) regular expressions:

```
'/test/:param1-:param2'  ==> '\/test\/(?:([^\/]+))-(?:([^\/]+))'
'/test/:param1*-:param2' ==> '\/test\/(?:(.+?))-(?:([^\/]+))'
```

So, what does each RegExp mean ?

---

#### /test/(?:([^/]+))-(?:([^/]+))

Let's break this up:

- `\/test\/`: Match the string '/test/'.
- `(?:([^\/]+))` is equivalent to `([^\/]+)` with the difference that we tell the RegExp engine not to store the capturing group's backreference.
  `([^\/]+)`: Match any sequence of 1 or more characters that does not contain `/`. By default, the RegExp engine will try to match as many characters as possible, **as long as** the rest of the string can match the remaining pattern (`-(?:([^\/]+))`).
- Since the **minimum** substring that matches `-(?:([^\/]+))` is `-doe`, `:param2` will be matched to `doe` and `:param1` to `42-john`.

#### /test/(?:(.+?))-(?:([^/]+))

Let's break this up:

- `\/test\/`: Match the string '/test/'.
- `(?:(.+?))` is equivalent to `(.+?)` with the difference that we tell the RegExp engine not to store the capturing group's backreference.
  `(.+?)`: **Non-greedily** match any sequence of 1 or more characters (any characters), **as long as** the rest of the string can match the remaining pattern (`-(?:([^\/]+))`). The key here is the `?` following `.+` which adds the *non-greedy* behaviour.
- Since the **minimum** substring that matches `(.+?)` (and on the same time let the rest of the string match `-(?:([^\/]+))`) is `42`, `:param1` will be matched to `42` and `:param2` to `john-doe`.

---

I hope this makes sense. Feel free to leave a comment if it doesn't :)